# How to upload an image to a server in adobe AIR?

Tags: adobe, air

I want to upload an image to a server in adobe AIR?
I am using php on the server side.
Can anyone give me a sample code to do this.
Also the code on the server side because I don't know how to get it on the serve side.
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

an example: http://www.lonhosford.com/lonblog/2010/07/29/adobe-air-native-drag-and-drop-file-upload-with-progressbar-and-php/